# InterSystems cache - how to insert into a join table?

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache, objectscript

The following objectscript will create the following SQL table:

**Objectscript Class**

```
Class MyApp.Parent Extends %Persistent
{
Property Children As array Of MyApp.Child;
}
```

**Parent_Children table and columns:**

```
Parent int NOT NULL,
ID varchar(254) NOT NULL,
Children int NULL,
element_key varchar(50) NOT NULL
```

When the Parent is saved in objectscript via the `%Save()` command and the Parent's children property has an element, a row is automatically created in this join table.  The `ID` column has a value like `"15||1",` the `Parent` column has the primary key of the `Parent` row and the `Children` column has the primary key of the child row.

In SQL, how do I create an insert statement for this table?  I do not know how to make the value for the ID column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a parent with ID of 1 and child with ID of 2 you could use:

```
Insert into MyApp.Parent_Children values (1,null,2,'fzj')
```

which would add a child with ID of 2 to the array of children for the parent with ID of 1, and have a key value in the array of "fzj".

Comment: That's odd, I thought ID was NOT NULL?  Also, element_key when generated by objectscript seems to represent the index of the children array, is it okay to put any value in there?

Comment: ID is NOT NULL, but also has a default value.  SQL will let you put any value in there, but if you are modeling an indexed array in object script you would want the SQL to match what the object expects.  So, yes, you would want to put the index of the children array.